# Appium Android - take screenshot returns "Illegal base64 character a"

Tags: java, android, appium, screenshot

I have Androud telephone connected via USB cable to my computer and I want to take screenshot when test fails:

I have the following code that returns error:

thisline returns error "File source = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);" - is there any different solution ?

```
public String getScreenshotPath(String testCaseName, AppiumDriver driver) throws IOException {

File source = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

String destinationFile = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//reports"+testCaseName+".png";

FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(destinationFile));

return destinationFile;

}
```

it returns error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character a

at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:746)
at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:538)
at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:561)
at org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$2.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:58)
at org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$2.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:55)
at org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$3.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:78)
at org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$3.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:75)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:335)
at utils.AppiumUtils.getScreenshotPath(AppiumUtils.java:73)
at Appium.AppiumMaven.Listeners.onTestFailure(Listeners.java:47)
at org.testng.internal.TestListenerHelper.runTestListeners(TestListenerHelper.java:99)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.runTestResultListener(TestInvoker.java:277)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:978)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:806)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:601)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:433)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:427)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:387)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Android Appium - how to take screenshot when telephone is connected via USB cable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74217681/java-android-appium-how-to-take-screenshot-when-telephone-is-connected-via-usb)

Comment: @Sim, Thanks for the link.  as Appium java client auto download latest Selenium driver. So, adding explicitly selenium 4.5.0 dependency resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

That's because there is an annoying thing Appium does when using it's driver to take a screenshot, but I'm not sure if this applies in your situation.

Can you  output the Base64 in the console to check it's specific output? If the output is something like this:

```
"Z3Rlc2dyZXNncmdyZWFncmVzZ3Jlc2dyZWFncmVzZ3Jlc2dlaW93YWpm\n"
"ZW9ndGVzZ3Jlc2dyZ3JlYWdyZXNncmVzZ3JlYWdyZXNncmVzZ2Vpb3dh\n"
"amZlb2d0ZXNncmVzZ3JncmVhZ3Jlc2dyZXNncmVhZ3Jlc2dyZXNnZWlv\n"
"d2FqZmVvZ3Rlc2dyZXNncmdyZWFncmVzZ3Jlc2dyZWFncmVzZ3Jlc2dl\n"
"aW93YWpmZW9ndGVzZ3Jlc2dyZ3JlYWdyZXNncmVzZ3JlYWdyZXNncmVz\n"
"Z2Vpb3dhamZlb2d0ZXNncmVzZ3JncmVhZ3Jlc2dyZXNncmVhZ3Jlc2dy\n"
```

Then you should replace the `"\n"` to a blank `""`:

```
String screenshotBase64 = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
String replaceBase64 = screenshotBase64.replaceAll("\n","");

doSomethingWith(replaceBase64);
```

Comment: This needs to be the accepted answer. Fixed the issue for me. Event though the question came first, your answer of the 'younger'  question is better. I.e., for anyone having the same issue follow the link.

Comment: You're right, I've changed my answer to the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

This related to some already known problem. Read https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1783

If you want to take screenshot for web app on android mobile devices, you must take screenshot as Base64 format and add this to DesiredCapabilites or UiAutomator2Options class:

```
UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
options.setNativeWebScreenshot(true);
```

For native app, I do not face this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have added below 2 dependencies and it worked for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>    <!-- Upgrading this version to higher, will fail test script taking screenshot -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>    <!-- Upgrading this version to higher, will fail test script taking screenshot -->
    </dependency>
```

I have initially added 4.6.0 and were showing same error, but now it worked with 4.5.0

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
getScenario().embed(((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES)

instead of:
File source = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

String destinationFile = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//reports"+testCaseName+".png";

FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(destinationFile));

return destinationFile;

Comment: does not work - same problem