# Java Android Appium - how to take screenshot when telephone is connected via USB cable?

Tags: android, appium, screenshot

Java Android Appium - how to take screenshot when telephone is connected via USB cable ?

The following line returns "Illegal base64 character a" - is there any different solution to take a screenshot ?

```
File source = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

I want to invoke screenshot when test fails in Test ng listeners Class:

```
@Override public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {}
```

Comment: Where do you wanna take that shot? And with what? Or.. where should your code run?

Comment: I want to invoke screenshot when test fails in Test ng listeners Class:  @Override
 public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) { }

Comment: You did not answer one of my questions.

Answer (score 1):

That's because there is an annoying thing Appium does when using it's driver to take a screenshot, but I'm not sure if this applies in your situation.

Can you  output the Base64 in the console to check it's specific output? If the output is something like this:

```
"Z3Rlc2dyZXNncmdyZWFncmVzZ3Jlc2dyZWFncmVzZ3Jlc2dlaW93YWpm\n"
"ZW9ndGVzZ3Jlc2dyZ3JlYWdyZXNncmVzZ3JlYWdyZXNncmVzZ2Vpb3dh\n"
"amZlb2d0ZXNncmVzZ3JncmVhZ3Jlc2dyZXNncmVhZ3Jlc2dyZXNnZWlv\n"
"d2FqZmVvZ3Rlc2dyZXNncmdyZWFncmVzZ3Jlc2dyZWFncmVzZ3Jlc2dl\n"
"aW93YWpmZW9ndGVzZ3Jlc2dyZ3JlYWdyZXNncmVzZ3JlYWdyZXNncmVz\n"
"Z2Vpb3dhamZlb2d0ZXNncmVzZ3JncmVhZ3Jlc2dyZXNncmVhZ3Jlc2dy\n"
```

Then you should replace the `"\n"` to a blank `""`:

```
String screenshotBase64 = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
String replaceBase64 = screenshotBase64.replaceAll("\n","");

doSomethingWith(replaceBase64);
```